# Which method should get fier after all the rendring done and inputEl have rendered

Tags: javascript, extjs

Which method should get fier after all the rendring done and inputEl have rendered.

I have tabpanel where I am using panel and pane have form and form have displayfield.

In my case my displayfield value is not getting render. That value is not available in dom. So I wanted to add those value manually.

```
Ext.fly(displayfield.id).set({ 'value': displayfield.value });
```

But the problem is

-afterender method is getting fiered before rendering iscompleted in dom. ANy suggestion which method should I use.

Answer (score 1):

Let the system do the work for you.

Set the value in the form panel's viewModel and bind the value property of the display field to the data property in the viewModel.

[Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3932)

```
    Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            viewModel: {
                data: {
                    field1: 'default view model'
                }
            },
            controller: {
                init: function(formPanel) {
                    formPanel.getViewModel().set('field1', 'New Display Value');  
                },
            },
            items: [{
                title: 'Title',
                bodyPadding: '10 15 0 10',
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox'
                },
                
                items: [{
                  xtype: 'displayfield',
                  name: 'field1',
                  bind: {
                      value: '{field1}'
                  },
                  value: 'default value',
                  fieldLabel: 'Field One'
                }]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```